# Scale tiny TileMap to a larger size in PyTMX and PyGame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pytmx

So I managed to create, import and display a 16x16 TileMap in my PyGame project.
I have my asset layer called *ground* and an Objects layer originally called *objects*.

[Tile software screenshot with my layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMnEP.png)

Then I've got this simple code to create my TileMap :

```
class TiledMap:
def __init__(self, filename):
    tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
    self.width = tm.width * TILE_SIZE
    self.height = tm.height * TILE_SIZE
    self.tmxdata = tm

def render(self, surface):
    ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
    for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
        if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
            for x, y, gid, in layer:
                tile = ti(gid)
                if tile:
                    tile = pg.transform.scale(tile,(TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE))
                    surface.blit(tile, (x * TILE_SIZE,
                                        y * TILE_SIZE))

def make_map(self):
    temp_surface = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height), pg.SRCALPHA).convert_alpha()
    self.render(temp_surface)
    return temp_surface
```

EDIT: I've forgot to say that my 16x16 map is actually rescaled to a 64x64 (TILE_SIZE) image, but only for the visible layer *ground*, I want to do it with the *objects* layer too.

This is working great to scale my "visible layer" which is *ground*.
But when I draw the collisions you can see that the *objects* are still really small and don't fit my new map resolution :

[Game screenshot with in Blue:Player hit box and in Yellow:Colliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGJlN.png)

As you can see the hit boxes of the **walls** I've set in my TileMap are not correctly scaled.

> So question is, how to scale the Objects layer of a TileMap with pyTMX ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a way to correct it, I don't know if it's the cleanest way to do it but here is the solution code :

```
def new(self):
    # Initialization and setup for a new game
    self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.items = pg.sprite.Group()

    for tile_object in self.map.tmxdata.objects:

        tile_object.x *= int(TILE_SIZE / self.map.tilesize)
        tile_object.y *= int(TILE_SIZE / self.map.tilesize)

        obj_center = vec(tile_object.x + tile_object.width / 2,
                         tile_object.y + tile_object.height / 2)

        if tile_object.name == 'player':
            self.player = Player(self, obj_center.x, obj_center.y)

        elif tile_object.name in ['pickaxe']:
            Item(self, obj_center, tile_object.name)

        else:
            tile_object.width *= int(TILE_SIZE / self.map.tilesize)
            tile_object.height *= int(TILE_SIZE / self.map.tilesize)

        # if tile_object.name == 'zombie':
        #     Mob(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y)

        if tile_object.name == 'wall':
            Obstacle(self, tile_object.x, tile_object.y, tile_object.width, tile_object.height)


    self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)
    self.paused = False
    self.draw_debug = False
```

So in my *game.new()* function I'm retrieving the sprites of the player and the objects by parsing a spritesheet and I already scale them to the correct size. But for the other entities size and for position the correction is simply to multiply the values with the correct number. Number which is the *scaling factor* : 16x16 to a 64x64 tilesets gives 64/16 which is 4.

> So I just had to multiply the entities x, y, width and height by 4.

Hope it will help someone anyway.